# How to have the Storybook `Primary` and `ArgsTable` components refer to a different component in a non MDX page

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to create a story for a component. For example:

**Button.stories.tsx:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ArgsTable,
  Description,
  Primary,
  Title,
} from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
import { Button as ButtonComponent, ButtonProps } from './Button';

export default {
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
  component: ButtonComponent,
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      page: () => (
        <>
          <Title />
          <Description />
          <Primary />
          <ArgsTable />
        </>
      ),
    },
  },
  title: 'Example/Button',
} as Meta;

export const ButtonParentComponent: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => (
  <>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <ButtonComponent {...args} />
  </>
);
```

However, I want to be able to have the `Primary` and `ArgsTable` addon-blocs not refer to `ButtonParentComponent` but instead refer to `ButtonComponent`. However, I still need `ButtonParentComponent` to be the component that is shown in my canvas.

The documentation currently seems unclear on how I can do this. It looks like I can refer to the story's name when using MDX, as mentioned [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/doc-blocks#for-stories), but it is unclear how I can do this for a non MDX file.

**To reproduce:**

1. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/jimmy-e/storybook-debug-v2)
2. Run `yarn && yarn storybook`

How can I have my `Primary` and `ArgsTable` components refer to a different component in a non MDX page? Thanks!